# replace string with jq

Tags: json, datetime, jq

I have the following file `file.txt`:

```
{"a": "a", "b": "a", "time": "20210210T10:10:00"}
{"a": "b", "b": "b", "time": "20210210T11:10:00"}
```

I extract the values with `bash` command `jq` (I use this command on massive 100g files):

```
jq -r '[.a, .b, .time] | @tsv'
```

This returns good result of:

```
a        a        20210210T10:10:00
b        b        20210210T11:10:00
```

The output I would like is:

```
a        a        2021-02-10 10:10:00
b        b        2021-02-10 11:10:00
```

The problem is that I want to change the format of the date in the most efficient way possible.
How do I do that?

Comment: Replace `(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})T` with  `\1-\2-\3 ` (including final space)?

Comment: You mean with `sed` ? something like `echo "20210427T19:23:00" | sed 's/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})T/\1-\2-\3/g'`? this command fails so I would love to get the working version of it :)

Comment: If I correcly remember, with sed you have to use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`, obtaining the replacement `'s/\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)T/\1-\2-\3/g'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sed:

```sh
$ echo "20210427T19:23:00" | sed -r 's|([[:digit:]]{4})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]
{2})T|\1-\2-\3 |'
2021-04-27 19:23:00
```

Comment: Marking this one as `sed` works 25% faster then @choroba solution. thanks both

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in sed, but you can also call `sub` directly in `jq`:

```
jq -r '[.a, .b,
           ( .time 
             | sub("(?<y>\\d{4})(?<m>\\d{2})(?<d>\\d{2})T";
                   .y+"-"+.m+"-"+.d+" ")
           )
       ] | @tsv'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `strptime` for date interpretation and `strftime` for formatting:

*parse.jq*

```
[ 
  .a,
  .b,
  ( .time
    | strptime("%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S")
    | strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S")
  )
] | @tsv
```

Run it like this:

```
<input.json jq -rf parse.jq
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
<input.json jq -r '[.a,.b,(.time|strptime("%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S")|strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S"))]|@tsv'
```

Output:

```
a   a   2021-10-02 10:10:00
b   b   2021-10-02 11:10:00
```

Answer (score 2):

Since speed is an issue, and since there does not appear to be a need for anything more than string splitting, you could compare string splitting done with jq using

```
[.a, .b,
 (.time | "\(.[:4])-\(.[4:6])-\(.[6:8]) \(.[9:])"]
```

vs similar splitting using `jq` with `awk -F\\t 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} ....'` (`awk` for ease of handling the TSV).