# remove a substring from a string

Tags: jq

I want to remove `,` from a string in jq. Take the following example, how to remove `,` when outputting `1,2`?

```
$ jq -r .x <<< '{"x":"1,2"}'
1,2
```

Comment: It's just [replace string with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67402313/12101554) but replace with an empty string

Answer (score 1):

To remove specific positions from a string, use the indices you want to keep:

```bash
jq -r '.x | .[:1] + .[2:]' <<< '{"x":"1,2"}'
```

```json
12
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/cltkT77Z7W)

To remove one occurrence at any position, use `sub` to replace with the empty string

```bash
jq -r '.x | sub(","; "")' <<< '{"x":"1,2,3"}'
```

```json
12,3
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/takIZcePxO)

To remove all occurrences, use `gsub` the same way

```bash
jq -r '.x | gsub(","; "")' <<< '{"x":"1,2,3"}'
```

```json
123
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/9objxxQHuc)

Comment: For the third example you could also use filter: `sub(",";"";"g")`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't make clear what output you wanted. A literal reading suggests you want `12`, but I find it more likely that you want each of the comma-separated items to be output on separate lines. The following achieves this:

```bash
jq -r '.x | split( "," )[]'
```

For the provided input, this outputs

```
1
2
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/4DVTQt5znew) on jqplay

But if `12` is indeed what's desired, adding a `join` will do the trick.

```bash
jq -r '.x | split( "," ) | join( "" )'
```

```
12
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ixlqAxjNA-5) on jqplay

Comment: I said removing ','. I didn't say adding newlines.

Comment: Then accept the other answer

Comment: I don't consent to use this feature on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub`.

Filter

```
.x | sub(","; " ")
```

Input

```
{"x":"1,2"}
```

Output

```
1 2
```

Demo

https://jqplay.org/s/IaViogZTsI